# How to read and fix console messages for *uninitialized* variables

Tags: javascript, php, variables, debugging, console

I am developing an application that reads a csv file and generates a report. It is working properly. However, when I run my application in Eclipse IDE, I see messages on the console that I am not sure if it is a problem or not.

I tried to use `isset` to fix the `uninitialized` variables and functions, but it did not solved my problem.  My question is: Should I worried about these messages? If, yes, how could I solve it? If I tried to run my application on a Unix server, I will a problem? I am having a hard time to interpret those messages.

```
[Wed May  1 09:03:30 2019] PHP Stack trace:
[Wed May  1 09:03:30 2019] PHP   1. {main}() C:\Users\jj-localadmin\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp6\htdocs\ReportApplication4.3\index.php:0
[Wed May  1 09:03:30 2019] PHP   2. require_once() C:\Users\jj-localadmin\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp6\htdocs\ReportApplication4.3\index.php:14
[Wed May  1 09:03:30 2019] PHP   3. create_xlsx() C:\Users\jj-localadmin\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp6\htdocs\ReportApplication4.3\controller\upload.php:38
[Wed May  1 09:03:30 2019] PHP   4. require_once() C:\Users\jj-localadmin\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp6\htdocs\ReportApplication4.3\controller\upload.php:60
[Wed May  1 09:03:30 2019] PHP   5. createStatisticsReport($file = *uninitialized*) C:\Users\jj-localadmin\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp6\htdocs\ExcelReportApplication4.3\model\xlsxGenerator.php:26
[Wed May  1 09:03:30 2019] PHP   6. usort(*uninitialized*, *uninitialized*) C:\Users\jj-localadmin\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp6\htdocs\ReportApplication4.3\model\xlsxGenerator.php:187
[Wed May  1 09:03:30 2019] PHP   7. cmp($a = *uninitialized*, $b = *uninitialized*) C:\Users\jj-localadmin\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp6\htdocs\ReportApplication4.3\model\xlsxGenerator.php:187
[Wed May  1 09:03:30 2019] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: First Name in C:\Users\jj-localadmin\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp6\htdocs\ReportApplication4.3\model\readStatisticsFile.php on line 102
[Wed May  1 09:03:30 2019] PHP Stack trace:
```

In 5. I am checking is the variable is empty, but it still giving the error.

Error:

```
[Wed May  1 09:03:30 2019] PHP   5. createStatisticsReport($file = *uninitialized*) C:\Users\jj-localadmin\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp6\htdocs\ExcelReportApplication4.3\model\xlsxGenerator.php:26
```

My code:

````
$fileName = 'data/uploadFile.csv'; // path for the csv file (registration and user statistics file are upload with the name)
if ($answer == "Statistics") {
    require_once 'readStatisticsFile.php';
    if (validateStatsFile($fileName) == 'true' && !empty($fileName))
                createStatisticsReport($fileName);```
````

Comment: Without the code which it's executing it's impossible to fix.

Comment: @NigelRen I added the code for line 26. Any clue how to solve it?